# C# windows service does not always stop on shutdown

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I created a windows service with c# 2010. The problem is that when computer shuts down the service does not have time to stop and onstop is not always executing. I say not always because sometime it manages to stop. I have tried to use windows pre-shutdown notification that was introduced at vista, however the results are better but not absolute.

Is there anyway to get windows wait for my service to stop?
Is there anyway to change the order windows stops the services?

Comment: Why doesn't your service have enough time to stop? Can you change the service so that it's prepared to stop faster?

Comment: My service does only one thing on_stop. It updates a record at sql server. It takes some milliseconds :)

Comment: Are you sure your service isn't stuck doing something else, thus not getting the event from Windows?

Comment: Several milliseconds should be fine. By chance, SQL server is not on the same computer, is it? If it is, it may be shut down before your service is. Would it be possible to update the record every time its data changes, or perhaps every few seconds on a timer? This way you'd be able to exit without any delay.

Comment: I have checked it. I have 2 lines of code on stop. One writing log that stop started, and one the sql update. After shutdown I check the log. About 60% stop runs and log saved. 40% no log, no sql update.

Comment: Are you wating somewhere for a handle or an event or something like that? Are you using an api that is doing this? I would not write my code beliving that the shutdown will allways be called. What happens if someone kills it?

Comment: No. Sql is on server. The record should be updated on shutdown because it update an application that the user switched off the pc.

Comment: I take the risk. It is not so critical information.

Comment: I suspect that @StevenVondruska is right - it's not that shutdown takes too long, as that the service never even tries.  Do you use `Thread.Sleep()` anywhere?

Comment: My onstop is this: protected override void OnStop() { changePbxStatus("Disconnected", "", ""); WriteLog("Service Closed : "); }
I read the logs of all these days and I can see that sometimes i stops perfectly. Some time does not stop at all and some times cannot connect to sql probably because the lan is stopped before my service...

Comment: @apant - Do you use `Thread.Sleep()`, `await` or any other type of pause in your service anywhere? Do you spin up extra threads?

Comment: No. I do not. The changePbxStatus opens connection to sql, updates a record and closes. Nothing more.

Comment: @apant - So the entirety of your service is to log when it gets shut down, nothing more?  Or is the whole thing simply a series of `change PbxStatus` calls?

Comment: @Bobson - changePbxStatus opens sql connection, updates ONLY one row and closes connection. Then the Writelog simply writes at log file that shutdown and the current time. That's all.

Comment: I read the log of the last days and I can also see the following error:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

I wonder if my computers shuts down the network before I update the sql record and that is my problem ......

Comment: Certainly possible.  Or it could have already shut down the database if that's on the same computer.

Comment: The database is not at the same computer. Is there any possibility to change the order computer stops services?

Answer (score 7):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx, a service normally has about 20 seconds to shut down before the system gives up and shuts down anyway.

You *might* be able to send `STOP_PENDING` messages back if your service needs more time to shut down, but even then you're limited to about 125 seconds before the system figures you're never going to shut down, and pulls the rug out from under you.

In C#, you would have your service call [RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) during shutdown. Again, there's no guarantee that you'll get that extra time, but you can ask for it. Remember, though, if you ask for more time you better be done before that time expires, or you can ask for more. But eventually the system *will* shut you down (again, probably in less than 2 minutes).

In general, I've found that it's best if you construct your service so that you can shut it down quickly. If you can't shut down in a few seconds, you probably need to change your design.

Answer (score 1):

This can be answer for you (and for somebody, who search same answer):
[Why doesn't the RequestAdditionalTime() method work on restart in Vista/7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011060/why-doesnt-the-requestadditionaltime-method-work-on-restart-in-vista-7#comment1932155_2011307):

> ... Suppose Windows allows 13 seconds for all services to shutdown. Some other service takes 12 seconds of cpu time (so other services can't execute during that time) and finally shuts down. That leaves 1 second for all the rest. Windows is going to kill them.

This is the reason, why it sometimes shutdown correctly a sometimes doesn't.

By the way, Vista has 20 sec. to kill services, W7 has 12 sec. and W8 has 5 sec.

Comment: Ok. I wonder if there is a way to get over this restriction and oblige windows to wait for this service to stop...

Comment: PreShutdown can block system shutdown and SENS Logoff signal can block system.

Answer (score 0):

In your service class derived from `ServiceBase`, in override of `OnStop` you can request for additional time:

```
base.RequestAdditionalTime(1000 * 60 * 2);
```

Comment: Also add it in your `OnShutdown`.

Comment: It still not always working :( Where exactly should I put this line? My onstop is the fillowing

Comment: protected override void OnStop()
        {
            changePbxStatus("Disconnected", "", "");
            WriteLog("Service Closed : ");
        }

Comment: I read the logs of all these days and I can see that sometimes i stops perfectly. Some time does not stop at all and some times cannot connect to sql probably because the lan is stopped before my service...

Comment: Put it at the beginning of your method; and you should have proper exception handling. Put your method's whole body in a `try { body } catch(Exception x) { log(x); }` for sometime to see what's happening there (I know that `catch(Exception x)` is a bad practice. But when we can not identify the source at runtime; it can help as diagnosis tool).

Comment: I put it at the beginning of the method with the same results.... I start believing that there is no solution to my problem....